# Como colocar no site login via facebook sempre logado

Tags: facebook

Na Api de login do facebook, tem como ficar o facebook sempre logado? 
Ou seja mesmo o usuário fechando o navegador da rede social que eu tenho, basta abrir digitar o site que já estará logado via facebook